# Datatable: how to fix both first row and first column?

Tags: jquery, css, datatables

I've a large table. (>50 cols, >100 rows).

I'm using [FixedHeader](https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedheader/) extension to keep first row fixed ad top. This works.

But i'm not able to enable the first COLUMN to stay fixed when user scroll horizontally, and I'm trying to do this using [FixedColumns](https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedcolumns/).

My actual init code is

```
$('#order_proposal_table').DataTable({
    'pageLength'    : 500,
    'fixedHeader'   : true,
    'fixedColumns'  :   {
        leftColumns: 1,
    },
    'sDom'          : 'lprtip ', // default was lfrtip, i repeat pagination both on top and on bottom
    'lengthMenu'    : [[10,25,50,100,250,500,-1], [10,25,50,100,250,500,'Tutte']],
    'language'      : {
        'url': '//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.10/i18n/Italian.json',
    }
});
```

The **problem** is that first rows remains fixed at top when user scroll vertically, ok, ***but*** when the user scroll the browser viewport horizontally to see all the other columns **the first columns  doesn't stay fixed at the left margin of the page**.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT 1:

I tried with `fixedColumns: true,`, but nothing changed.

EDIT 2:

I, just now, can see this info in the javascript console:

```
DataTables warning: table id=order_proposal_table - FixedColumns is not
needed (no x-scrolling in DataTables enabled), so no action will be
taken. Use 'FixedHeader' for column fixing when scrolling is not enabled
```

Can this help you to help me?

Comment: Does changing the fixedColumns to `'fixedColumns': true` make any difference?

Comment: @lvar: (I updated the question) NO, your suggestion give no results

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable({
    scrollY: 300,
    scrollX: true,
    scrollCollapse: true,
    paging: false,
    fixedColumns: true
  });
});
```

```css
/* Ensure that the demo table scrolls */

th,
td {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
div.dataTables_wrapper {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedcolumns/3.2.0/css/fixedColumns.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedcolumns/3.2.0/js/dataTables.fixedColumns.min.js"></script>

<table id="example" class="stripe row-border order-column" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First name</th>
      <th>Last name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
      <th>Extn.</th>
      <th>E-mail</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Olivia</td>
      <td>Liang</td>
      <td>Support Engineer</td>
      <td>Singapore</td>
      <td>64</td>
      <td>2011/02/03</td>
      <td>$234,500</td>
      <td>2120</td>
      <td>o.liang@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bruno</td>
      <td>Nash</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>38</td>
      <td>2011/05/03</td>
      <td>$163,500</td>
      <td>6222</td>
      <td>b.nash@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sakura</td>
      <td>Yamamoto</td>
      <td>Support Engineer</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>37</td>
      <td>2009/08/19</td>
      <td>$139,575</td>
      <td>9383</td>
      <td>s.yamamoto@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Thor</td>
      <td>Walton</td>
      <td>Developer</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2013/08/11</td>
      <td>$98,540</td>
      <td>8327</td>
      <td>t.walton@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Finn</td>
      <td>Camacho</td>
      <td>Support Engineer</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>47</td>
      <td>2009/07/07</td>
      <td>$87,500</td>
      <td>2927</td>
      <td>f.camacho@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Serge</td>
      <td>Baldwin</td>
      <td>Data Coordinator</td>
      <td>Singapore</td>
      <td>64</td>
      <td>2012/04/09</td>
      <td>$138,575</td>
      <td>8352</td>
      <td>s.baldwin@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Zenaida</td>
      <td>Frank</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>63</td>
      <td>2010/01/04</td>
      <td>$125,250</td>
      <td>7439</td>
      <td>z.frank@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Zorita</td>
      <td>Serrano</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>56</td>
      <td>2012/06/01</td>
      <td>$115,000</td>
      <td>4389</td>
      <td>z.serrano@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jennifer</td>
      <td>Acosta</td>
      <td>Junior Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>43</td>
      <td>2013/02/01</td>
      <td>$75,650</td>
      <td>3431</td>
      <td>j.acosta@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cara</td>
      <td>Stevens</td>
      <td>Sales Assistant</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>46</td>
      <td>2011/12/06</td>
      <td>$145,600</td>
      <td>3990</td>
      <td>c.stevens@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Hermione</td>
      <td>Butler</td>
      <td>Regional Director</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>47</td>
      <td>2011/03/21</td>
      <td>$356,250</td>
      <td>1016</td>
      <td>h.butler@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lael</td>
      <td>Greer</td>
      <td>Systems Administrator</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>21</td>
      <td>2009/02/27</td>
      <td>$103,500</td>
      <td>6733</td>
      <td>l.greer@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jonas</td>
      <td>Alexander</td>
      <td>Developer</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>2010/07/14</td>
      <td>$86,500</td>
      <td>8196</td>
      <td>j.alexander@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Shad</td>
      <td>Decker</td>
      <td>Regional Director</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>51</td>
      <td>2008/11/13</td>
      <td>$183,000</td>
      <td>6373</td>
      <td>s.decker@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Michael</td>
      <td>Bruce</td>
      <td>Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>Singapore</td>
      <td>29</td>
      <td>2011/06/27</td>
      <td>$183,000</td>
      <td>5384</td>
      <td>m.bruce@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Donna</td>
      <td>Snider</td>
      <td>Customer Support</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
      <td>4226</td>
      <td>d.snider@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/x66ymo4r/)
I think you have not include [Fixed Table plugin Datatable CSS](https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedcolumns/3.2.0/css/fixedColumns.dataTables.min.css)  and [Fixed Datable JS](https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedcolumns/3.2.0/js/dataTables.fixedColumns.min.js)  [Source](https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedcolumns/examples/initialisation/simple.html)

Comment: Your example works but it's a bad result: when scrolling horizzontal, the first row MUST also scroll.

Comment: @realtebo Sorry i didn't get , i can see all rows in table scrolling horizontal

Comment: sorry, now it works... previously when  I scrolled horizontally, the header row stayed fixed, so column header didn't match column data... strange glitch, no more happening...

Comment: @CY5 The doc says `FixedHeader is not currently compatible with tables that have the scrolling features of DataTables enabled`. Does this mean headers can't be fixed when we use `scrollY` option.

Comment: How to fix more than 1 columns? When I define like `leftColumns: 2` it doesn't work. can you please help.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem might be, that you are missing the `scrollX: true` property.

```
$('#order_proposal_table').DataTable({
    'pageLength'    : 500,
    'fixedHeader'   : true,
    'scrollX'       : true,
    'fixedColumns'  :   {
        leftColumns: 1,
    },
    'sDom'          : 'lprtip ', // default was lfrtip, i repeat pagination both on top and on bottom
    'lengthMenu'    : [[10,25,50,100,250,500,-1], [10,25,50,100,250,500,'Tutte']],
    'language'      : {
        'url': '//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.10/i18n/Italian.json',
    }
});
```

See these examples:

https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedcolumns/examples/initialisation/simple.html

and

https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedcolumns/examples/initialisation/left_right_columns.html